Interpretation of an asymptotic result in probability
A result in asymptotic theory says the following: Let $Y$ be a real random variable with full support and $E(|Y|)<\infty$. Assume that:
$$
(A)\quad \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Pr(Y\geq y)}{\Pr(Y\geq \kappa h(y))}=1
$$
for some $\kappa>0$ and function $h$ such that $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} h'(y)=1            $. Then, $\kappa=1$.
Could you help me understand:(1) How to interpret $(A)$; (2) How to interpret the result that $\kappa$ must be 1; (3) Why would you expect this result to intuitively hold or not hold?

Thoughts. Regarding (1): The limiting condition says that $ h(y) =\alpha+  y $  in the limit. Then, I think it holds that
$$
(B)\quad \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \Pr(Y \geq y) = \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \Pr(Y \geq \kappa h(y)) = 0.
$$
Assumption $(A)$ is stronger than $(B)$, because I think  $(A)$ says that $\Pr(Y \geq y)$ and $\Pr(Y \geq \kappa h(y))$ go to zero at the same rate (but I am not sure here about this).
Regarding (2):   Somehow, this result suggests that if $(A)$ holds, then $h$ can   shift and rescale $y$ (in the limit), but the multiplicative constant $\kappa$ in front of $h$ must be one. Is this a correct interpretation of the result?
Regarding (3):  I have zero intuition. If my interpretation of the result is correct (see above), why can $h$ be anything and $\kappa$ must instead be one?

@Algernon So sorry, my mistake! The first derivative is 1 in the limit

$\newcommand\ka\kappa$Intuition for this result is as follows.
The condition on $h'$ implies that $h(y)=(1+o(1))y$ (as $y\to\infty$). So, for the tail function $T$ given by $T(y):=P(Y\ge y)$ we have
$$T(y)=(1+o(1))T(\ka h(y)) =(1+o(1))T((\ka+o(1))y) \tag{1}\label{1}.$$
So, if $\ka\in(0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$, then $T(y)$ cannot decrease to $0$ faster than $y^{-p}$, for any real $p>0$. So, then we can expect that
$$E\max(0,Y)^p=\int_0^\infty dy\,py^{p-1}T(y)=\infty$$
for any real $p>0$, which would contradict the condition $E|Y|<\infty$.

This intuition is easy to convert to a formal proof, as follows. Moreover, instead of your condition on $h'$, it is enough to assume its less restrictive consequence that $h(y)=(1+o(1))y$ (as $y\to\infty$). Furthermore, instead of your condition $E|Y|<\infty$, it is enough to assume its less restrictive consequence that $E\max(0,Y)^p<\infty$ for some real $p>0$.
Indeed, without loss of generality $\ka>1$. (If $\ka\in(0,1)$, rewrite \eqref{1} as $T(y)=(1+o(1))T((1/\ka+o(1))y))$. Take now any $k\in(1,\ka)$. Then \eqref{1} and the full support condition imply that
$$T(ky)\ge k^{-p} T(y)>0$$
for some real $y_0>0$ and all real $y\ge y_0$. So,
$$y\in[k^n y_0,k^{n+1}y_0)\implies T(y)\ge T(k^{n+1}y_0)\ge k^{-(n+1)p} T(y_0).$$
So,
$$E\max(0,Y)^p=\int_0^\infty dy\,py^{p-1}T(y) \\ 
\ge\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{k^n y_0}^{k^{n+1}y_0} dy\,py^{p-1}k^{-(n+1)p} T(y_0)
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-k^{-p})y_0^p T(y_0)
=\infty,$$
which contradicts the condition $E\max(0,Y)^p<\infty$.

@Algernon : We can even have something like $h(y)=y+\ln y$ for $y>1$, but of course  $h(y)=(1+o(1))y$ will be true anyway, with the given condition on $h'$.

Thanks. Would you mind add something about my questions (1) and (2), also in relation with my (likely wrong) thoughts? Lastly, could you please add a few more details about the steps of the intuition? For example, the sentence "So, for the tail function..." and the implication about the rate are not very clear to me

@Star : (i) Your condition (A) is "interpreted" as my condition (1), which roughly means that $T(\kappa y)$ behaves as $T(y)$ for large $y$. (ii) Your questions (2) and (3) are essentially the same.  (iii) Your thoughts are not quite good. In particular, you can have $h(y)=y+\ln y$ for $y>1$. Also, your (B) holds whenever $h(y)\to\infty$ as $y\to\infty$, and the latter condition is much less restrictive than your condition on $h'$ or my condition $h(y)=(1+o(1))y$  -- take e.g. $h(y)=y^a$ for any real $a>0$.

Previous comment continued: MathOverflow guidelines say that users should not answer posts that "request answers to multiple questions". So, I suggest you remove your questions (1) and (2), and leave only question (3), which essentially covers your questions (1) and (2) anyway.

@Star : I have also added a detail in my formula (1).

@IosifPinelis Thanks for taking the time to help me with this. Before cleaning my question following your comments, may I ask: (I) is my (B) weaker than my (A)? (II) In your intuition arguments, how do you go from (1) to saying that $T(y)$ cannot go to zero faster than $y^{-p}$?

@Star : (I) Yes, as I noted in my previous comment, your (B) is much weaker (that is, much less restrictive) than your (A). (II) If, say, $T(y)\sim y^{-p}$, then the limit in your condition (A) would be $\kappa^p\ne1$ if $\kappa\ne1$.

Thanks. (II) I can't understand why that limit would be $\kappa^p$, sorry.

@Star : Because $T(y)\sim y^{-p}$ and $h(y)\sim y$, and hence $T(\kappa h(y))\sim (\kappa h(y))^{-p}=\kappa^{-p} h(y)^{-p}\sim \kappa^{-p} y^{-p}$.

@Star : Thank you for your comments.
